# Create 1px sidebar divider in bootstrap from end to end of wrapper

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sidebar, divider

I am trying to create a sidebar divider that will touch the edge of the wrapper (both top and bottom), which will auto adjust in height as more content gets added. When the browser width resizes and the information collapses, I want the divider to disappear.

Here is the site: http://bobbyomari.com/opa/

Here's my code:

```
        <div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">

        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

<!-- BODY -->
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <h3>Campus News</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>

<!-- SIDEBAR -->            
            <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="sidebar-divider hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                <h3>Calendar of Events</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.sidebar-divider {
border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
top: 0;
right: 0;
padding-left: 30px;
}

.wrapper {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
background-color: #fff;
border-radius: 3px
border: 1px solid #ccc;
margin: 30px 0px; 
padding: 30px 30px;
}
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could draw it from a pseudo element set in absolute positionning.

```
div.wrapper {
position:relative
}
/* ! remove sidebar-divider border */
div.wrapper:before {
content:'';
border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
position:absolute!important;
top:0;
bottom:0;
right:24.25%;
}
```

it could be drawn from .sidebar-divider too with a bit more CSS

```
div.wrapper {
position:relative
}
div.wrapper * {
position:static;
border:none;
}
/* ! remove sidebar-divider border */
div.sidebar-divider:before {
content:'';
border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
position:absolute!important;
top:0;
bottom:0;
right:24.25%;
}
```

Comment: That worked great! The only thing is that I was hoping to use "hidden-xs" and "hidden-sm" to hide the divider. If you view my source code, you can see that I put it in, but it hides all the content as well.

I also have this issue with the carousel. The blue background goes to about half of the slider with the wrapper that goes about 60px below the slider. When you resize the browser width it just messes up altogether.

Comment: you can rewrite the selector : div.sidebar-divider:before like div.sidebar-divider.hidden-xs:before or  div.sidebar-divider.hidden-sm:before , for the rest it turns to be a new question and will confuse anyone trying to help you with that border problem. lets fix that border first

Comment: Alright, so I am pretty sure I did it wrong, but what I did was changed "div.sidebar-divider:before" to ""div.sidebar-divider.hidden-xs:before". It didn't work, so I am sure I did something wrong. If you check the site, you can see what I changed. "hidden-xs" should still be inside "<div class="sidebar-divider hidden-xs"> correct? Sorry, I'm a noob at this, but I'm learning!

Comment: Made some changes, still can't seem to get it to work. I tried using div.sidebar-divider.hidden-xs and it just hides the content and sidebar. Also. how can I create padding to the left of the divider? I tried using padding and margin, but no luck. Just made the right side padding larger. Thoughts?

Comment: just got back, it seems to work in my FF, maybe some padding needs tunning

Comment: Ok I got it to work with hidden-xs, hidden-sm. I had to re-arrange the html around a little. So yea the only thing I have issue now with is the padding on the left side. I don't think margin-left or margin-right will work. Do I have to create a wrapper for the body content?

Comment: would this update will do ? div.sidebar-divider:after {
 content:'';
 border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
 position: absolute!important;
 top:0;
 bottom:0;
 right:26%;
}

Comment: Adjusted to 27% which seems close to 30px padding I want on the right, but if you notice on the left, there's little to no padding. http://i.imgur.com/b4vqkze.png Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: ha, the other round, so it could be : div.col-md-9 {
padding-right:2em;/* or so */
}

Comment: Awesome!! Worked great. Thanks so much. Now I am on part 2 of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21171243/two-backgrounds-with-overlapping-slider-carousel-and-navigation-with-bootstrap